# Get API Key for adsense requests

Tags: google-api, request

I'm using the API Explorer tool to create some request urls for google adsense [here](https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/v1.4/reference/reports/generate#auth). Here is the request url that they gave me that gives a response of today's earnings: 
`https://www.googleapis.com/adsense/v1.4/reports?startDate=today&endDate=today&accountId=MY_ACCOUNT_ID&metric=EARNINGS&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

However, I don't know how to get my API key for google developer to be able to recreate this url in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API key is created on the Cloud Platform Console. Please refer to [this document](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158862?hl=en) and you will be able to do it. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. I don't know why that was so hard for me to find.